# Why does my keyboard language switch on website password fields?

Tags: keyboard, macos, password, input-source

Using a Mac with Mavericks, I have keyboard setup to Hebrew. Then, when I click in the password field, it switches it back to English and Hebrew is disabled.

[image]
[image]

I saw that [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6810/why-does-my-keyboard-switch-language-in-most-input-fields-on-the-web) says to remove the keyboards, but I need to keep both Hebrew and US input methods active. I don't use quicksilver and wonder if something else might cause this problem on Mavericks?

Comment: Is this independent of your browser? I have noticed that Mavericks auto changes the keyboard layout to your system locale when entering passwords in the user login window. Maybe the same happens in Safari now...

Comment: I observe the same behaviour when using chrome. However, it did not happen in safari nor firefox (same settings and same website).

Comment: I found a fix presented in [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/6810/) related question.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a little bit of testing, I think it's because of this option is enabled in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Input Sources**:

[image: Automatically switch to a document's input source]

It's checked by default and since cbs.com is in English, OS X will automatically change the input source to English (If you don't have English, or whatever language the page is in,  enabled, it seems it'll just select your default input source — i.e. the one at the top of the list in **Input Sources**).

I tested with Hebrew and Danish enabled and when focusing a textfield OS X changed my keyboard layout to Danish *with* auto-switch enabled and *didn't* with it disabled.

At least in my case, the swithcing wasn't limited to password fields specifically (which makes sense). The behaviour is the same in both Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Sadly this does not fix my problem (macOS 10.14 Mojave). Last version worked just fine and also other programms work with other layouts.