# Cannot type non-english text in html password fields

Tags: keyboard, password, language

When focus is on an html password field, the input languages options are limited to those using the Latin script only. If the language selected is some other language using a non-Latin script, like Greek, before going into the password field, it is automatically switched to one for Latin when focus goes onto the password field. This happens on all browsers I've tested: Safari (8.0.5), Chrome (51.0.2704.103), Firefox (47.0). I've tried it on Mountain Lion, Yosemite and EL Capitan.

I have tried disabling the keyboard shortcut for switching languages but the problem remains.

The option "Automatically switch to an document's input source" mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119313/why-does-my-keyboard-language-switch-on-website-password-fields) is not enabled.

The non-english languages are simply disabled when focus is on a password field.

Here is a minimal html document which demonstrates the problem:

```
<html>
<form>
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
</html>
```

Here is a screenshot when focus is on the password field:
[image]

Comment: What language is it that you want to input?  There is no input source named "English".  Are you referring to "US"?  The US input source can also be used to write various Western European languages besides English.

Comment: Well I've tried input languages US and British, they both work. Other input sources such as Greek, Armenian, Arabic do not work. I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: Your question should be modified to refer to input sources for Latin Script.  That includes quite a few languages other than English.

Comment: Do you find this to be a problem on real websites that you yourself use?

Comment: Yes, of course.